# Insufficient info for moderator vote

Tags: feature-request, moderators, election

I think the information presented on the moderator voting page is not really sufficient to make an informed decision.  Moderators are not really just good SO users but are active SO citizens who help SO.  This has a lot more to do with editing and commenting and less on the quality/quantity of their questions/answers.

Unfortunately, information on edits/comments is not available.  It would be nice if this information could be made available in relation to moderator voting (i.e., links to specific edits and comments).

Comment: +1, I wish my edit history were available.  It is a large portion of my contribution to the site.

Comment: I am not sure edits or comments have anything to do with being a moderator.

Comment: It axiomatic that that the *best* moderator is the person you are not going to notice. They work behind the scenes, not necessarily contributing in the most visible ways or making a spectacle of themselves. It's hard to pull up good data for all the work that you *don't* see.

Comment: @Robert: Very well-said. I've been in that behind-the-scenes mode for quite some time. I care heavily about the sites, but rarely find questions I can/want to answer. But I **always** find posts worth editing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Some* of the nominees' recent editing and commenting history is available, although their closure history (equally important) isn't. That information can be viewed via the "Activity" tab on the nominees' profiles.

Now, I'll be the first to grant that this isn't exactly an *optimal* solution -- there's a very finite amount of information there. However, it is something to go on when making your decision.

Answer (score -1):

How would anyone choose which edits and comments should be attached?